# Datatables oLanguage (internationalisation) default setting

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

I have a problem with setting up i18n in datatables.
I know there is the oLanguage setting, which can point to an url, or which can be naually overwritten. But the problem is, that I need to to be set for ALL datatables on the page.
Any other settings can be preset by extending the default options, but this does not work with the oLanguage for some reason.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // set up defaults for datatables
    $.extend( $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
        "bFilter": false,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bLengthChange":false,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "sDom": 'rtp',
        "oLanguage": {
            "sUrl": "themes/simple/javascript/dataTables-sk.js"
        },
        "bServerSide": true

    });
});
```

When I do it at initialisation, it works:

```
$('table').dataTable( {
   "oLanguage": {
      "sUrl": "themes/simple/javascript/dataTables-sk.js"
   },
});
```

Any idea where the problem is?

Comment: Do you get any errors? That should work exactly as you have done it above.

Comment: yes, i get some error in the datatables core - I have the minimized one, so hard to tell - maybe i will try it with the non-minimized one
But it has to do sth with the website itself, as I tried in jsfiddle and it worked :(

Comment: Have you tried an absolute path?

Comment: yes. the problem seems to be something else.. i get the data language file loaded, but still the script crashes on some undefined function "G". It seems to have nohting in common with the language, but when I leave this option out, eveyrhing works fine

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I haven't found out anything more about this. It seems to be a very specifi bug to a specific system (I was using the Silverstripe framework), and on any other system/framework this works without any problems

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if its exactly your problem, but one time i need to localize all my DataTables, and i extend the oLanguage default property like this:

```
    $.extend( true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
    oLanguage : {
        "sProcessing":     "Procesando...",
        "sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
        "sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron resultados",
        "sEmptyTable":     "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
        "sInfo":           "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
        "sInfoEmpty":      "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
        "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
        "sInfoPostFix":    "",
        "sSearch":         "Buscar:",
        "sUrl":            "",
        "sInfoThousands":  ",",
        "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
        "oPaginate": {
            "sFirst":    "Primero",
            "sLast":     "Último",
            "sNext":     "Siguiente",
            "sPrevious": "Anterior"
        },
        "oAria": {
            "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
            "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
        }
    }
});
```

I put it in a script that i render in top of my page, and all the DataTables in my app become localized. In my case i get the translation in the offitial DataTables translations page (Spanish in my case):

https://datatables.net/plug-ins/i18n/

I dont know if im so late, but i find this question recently.

Sorry about my English.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This question was a long time ago, but I fixed it setting the desired language to be default in jquery.data-tables.js,in the "oPaginate": "sUrl" as you said, but I put the direct link, in my case:

```
"sUrl": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.13/i18n/Portuguese-Brasil.json"
```

Hope it help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with DataTables 1.10.12. Tried different combinations similar to what @ruben-dario-perez wrote, but I only wanted to modify a few strings, and I was getting an error that "oPaginate" was not defined. Changing "oLanguage" to "language" made it work! Here's how my code looks like:

```
$.extend($.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
language: {
    sInfo: GlobalTranslations.Showing_START_to_END_of_TOTAL_entries,
    sInfoEmpty: GlobalTranslations.ListEmpty,
    sEmptyTable: GlobalTranslations.ListEmpty
}});
```